# Show "no data" for Visuals which becomes blank after selection of filter

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to hide or mask such visuals which becomes blank after selection of filter(s). Following is an example.

I have table like -

[image]

Following is report -

[image]

Where, I have used Metric column as Slicer and the visuals are Metric wise. So, When I do select metric(s) , Then the visual(s) shows chart for the metric(s), but other shows as blank or nothing. So I want to show "No Preview" or "No data" for the blank visuals.
Like below -

[image]

Please suggest.

Thanks and Appreciation in advance !!

Comment: Can you post DAX formulas you've used for the visuals?

Comment: There is no DAX formula, Since these (Records and Revenue) are columns with numeric values so aggregating (sum) it self.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible on cards and matrix only, and not on the bar and many other types of chart.

You will have to create a measure like the following:

```
Total Revenue = 
VAR TotalRevenu = SUM(Table1[Revenue])
RETURN 
    IF(
        ISBLANK(TotalRevenue),
        "No Data",
        TotalRevenue
    )
```

As mentioned, this will work for cards and matrix values only.